# SQL Server Date Diff On Rows In Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query that groups a start and stop time on different rows, where Batch Number 1 is the start, and BatchNumber 2 is the stop time, and I need to do a datediff on them. I have tried adding row numbers and trying to do something like date diff rows 1 and 2, 3 and 4, etc, with no luck.

So I have to do a date diff on 1 and 3, 2 and 4, and so on whenever there is batch 1 and 2 together.

Here is what my data looks like:

```
RowNumber  OrderNumber  IDCode    DateVal              MilestoneID   BatchNumber
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1          5017555.1    4077213   2018-08-30 12:22:51.253  15           1
3          5017555.1    4081502   2018-09-05 12:41:08.817  16           2
2          5017555.1    4095474   2018-09-18 10:42:47.457  15           1
4          5017555.1    4095665   2018-09-18 12:07:11.083  16           2
```

Comment: Are those RowNumber values correct?

Comment: And where is the start and stop time?  I see nothing that looks like a date or time data type.

Comment: So you have already a query that calculates those batch numbers?

Comment: The start time is row 1 batchnumber one and the value is in DateVal, the stop time is row number 3 batch number 2 DateVal.

Comment: Sorry, my copy formatting was all messed up, so I edited it to be the proper datetime values. I do have a query that pulls the start and end times out and groups them into 1, and 2 for start and stop.

Comment: Add SQL server version. You're unable to use `LAG` so the version number matters.

Comment: Version 10.50.2550.0, however, LAG is compatibility, isn't it? Which mine is at 90, not the 110 which is required for LEAD and LAG.

Comment: @TerryMinton I believe by 10.50.2550.0 you mean SQL Server 2008 R2. Nope, LEAD/LAG requires SQL Server 2012. Compatibility level does not matter in this case. You need old school solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

LAG allows you to get value from a previous row:

```
Select * 
datediff (day, LAG(DateVal) OVER (ORDER BY OrderNumber) ,DateVal ) 
From YourTable
```

You can also use [Lead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to get value from next row

Comment: Would also want to add a `PARTITION BY BatchNumber`

Comment: LAG did not work for me, and I am using SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: SELECT A.OrderNumber, 
A.BatchNumber, 
A.DateVal,
datediff (day, LAG(A.DateVal) OVER (ORDER BY A.OrderNumber) ,A.DateVal ) 
From #HoldTimes A

Comment: Says LAG is not a recognized built in function name in SSMS.

Comment: Check your  COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL. If it is possible set it at least to 110: ALTER DATABASE DBName SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110

Comment: I don't have access to do that, but I can try to have it done. Mine is set at 90 right now.

Comment: That is the reason, why LAG and LEAD don't work. You can also use CURSOR, but it will significantly reduce conformance